# WPF Converters Guidelines

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

Is there any guidelines about converters implementation. I would like to refactor all may converters and I think it would be nice if it will correspond to some conventional ways. Strangely I haven't googled anything useful.
I am curious about the following topics:

1. Should I have several converters like EnumStringConverter, EnumValuesConverter or just single EnumConverter where I check 'targetType' and return corresponding result?
2. How to name: FooToBooConverter or FooBooConverter?
3. Should I care about targetType, type of value, have assertion for it?

Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: 4. What should we do when can't convert: throw an exception, return Binding.DoNothing or DependencyProperty.UnsetValue or even just null?

Comment: To 4: I think MSDN may be treated as guidelines http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific guidelines for Converter implementations. rather then asking for converter guide lines search for C# guide lines. for reference look at below links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18309/Coding-Standards-for-C-Names

I think you must use the Re-Sharper for codding helps.

now about your questions.

1. Creating multiple converter are make your code easy and follow the Single responsibly principle. So for any reason you only change in specific class. that will not impact on another features.
2. Naming conversion is good to be readable so someone else who will join your team will easily read and understand for e.g FooToBooConverter is good. its readable. but FooBooConverter is little complected to understand by name.
3. You Should care about the Specific Target Type. for generic type you don't need to care. like Converting color from number. for this thing you don't have to worry about.

hopefully these all resolve your query.

I suggest you to read about the SOLID Principles.

http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=1001061&page=3